# dojo datagrid IndirectSelection also selects the disabled cells

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

By selecting all rows in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hh8Ub/ you will notice that the disabled checkboxes (rows 1, 3 and 5) are also selected. 
I've seen same behaviour in dojo 1.9

One way to solve this might be to modify the `toggleAllSelection` and run a function foreach row to check if the checkbox is disabled first, but I would rather not to.

this is the toggleAllSelection function:

```
toggleAllSelection:function(checked){
    // summary:
    //      Toggle select all|deselect all
    // checked: Boolean
    //      True - select all, False - deselect all

    var grid = this.grid, selection = grid.selection;
    if(checked){
        selection.selectRange(0, grid.rowCount-1);
    }else{
        selection.deselectAll();
    }
    this.toggleAllTrigerred = true;
},
```

thanks in advance

Comment: can you modify dojo 1.9 file, if yes then just put one condition to check if checkbox is enable then make selection otherwise don't do anything

Comment: updated the question with the toggleAllSelection function, which just gets the rowcount and checks the checkboxes. no mater they are disabled or not. I have to override this function in order to go through all the rows and check for the disabled state of the row..

Comment: yes you need to modify toggleAllSelection function, to make it work